# Using a varible in another method whose value has been changed in an actionListener i

Tags: java, string, variables, actionlistener

I need to use the String `P` in the following code in another `method(arrive)`. String `P` has been assigned a new value in the actionListener.

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent hh)//Method to perform action on clicking 
                            {
                                f=cb.getSelectedIndex();
                                for(i=0;i<c;i++)
                                {
                                    if(i==f)
                                    {
                                        P=copy2[i];
                                    }
                                }
                                try
                                {
                                    frame.pack();
                                    frame.dispose();
                                    obj.arrive();
                                }
                                catch(IOException e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Any suggestions would be valuable.

Comment: P doesn't seem to be locally defined in that method, so if it is some class field where's the problem in using it outside of the method that modifies it?

Comment: Thanks for responding to my post George. Despite the fact that it is not locally defined, I am unable to use the new value of the string P. For example, in one case let's say P becomes "New York", then I am unable to print this same value in another method

Comment: When you say unable, do you mean that it prints some other value? What IDE do you use for development? Some allow you to right click a name and see all references of it and also where it is defined. Is there a chance there are two different P fields? Also add some message printing to a log or console or a breakpoint to make sure that assignment is called - place it right after the assignment and in the same parent code block

Comment: When I declare the variable in the class, I am stating String P="". Despite the fact that P has been changed to "New York"(for example), the output is "". I am using BlueJ as my IDE. By the way, the following code is embedded in another actionListener. I want to be able to access this String outside both of these ActionListeners, in another method.

Comment: You need to call the other methods AFTER you change the value

Comment: I am doing exactly that. Please refer to the given code.

Comment: please do String P="test"; at the class level (not in the constructor). Does it then print "test" at your logging point or does it still print ""?

Comment: Yes, it prints "test", but the problem occurs inside the actionListener. Please let me know if you want to view the full code. The problem is that the full code occupies too much space